# PHP Script to inform client if name is in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie with PHP coding, so bear with me.  I have a MySQL database that is a list of names, birthdates, dependents, and SSNs.
I've created a simple form with just a textbox for a name and a submit button.
I want my PHP script to check the database and if the name not there it should return a message that says, "Your name is not listed"; otherwise it should return the clients first and last name and their birthdate.
The code I've written returns the entire list of names and birthdates regardless of what I've typed in the textbox.  Why is it doing this, where have I made my error?

The response looks like this:
Joe Bean
Your date of birth is: 1988-11-05
 Danielle Davis
Your date of birth is: 1944-12-13
 Angela Dawnell
Your date of birth is: 1988-09-24
 David Depaoli
Your date of birth is: 1988-10-15 ....etc

My PHP code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("USE myDatabase");  
$s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY lastname");                 
$rows=mysql_numrows($s);
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
{
$f=(mysql_result($s,$i,"firstname"));                  
$l=(mysql_result($s,$i,"lastname"));
$b=(mysql_result($s,$i,"birthdate"));
if($rows == 0)
{
print $l. " Your name is not listed.";
}
else
{print "<br /> $f " . "$l";
print "<br />Your date of birth is: " . $b;
}   
}  
// mysql_query("DROP DATABASE myDatabase") or die(mysql_error());            
mysql_close();     
?>
```

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/proj10.php" method="post">
<label for="fname">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="20"><br><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="     Submit       "onclick = "check  ('lname');">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions, they are officially deprecated

Comment: Yes. Look at the PDO section in PHP man.

Comment: Why this: // mysql_query("DROP DATABASE myDatabase") ? :D

Comment: You might show us javascript containing check() function<;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you can use mysql_*() as test purpose, you should migrate to mysqli_*() or PDO for the life time of your code. Nevertheless, you have error in your code in point of view PHP:

```
<?php
$lname = isset($_POST["lname"]) ? $_POST["lname"] : "";
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("myDatabase");
$s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable
  WHERE lastname LIKE '%$lname%'
  ORDER BY lastname;");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($s);
if($rows == 0)
{
  echo $lname . " Your name is not listed.";
}
else
{
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($s))
  {
    $f = $row["firstname"];                  
    $l = $row["lastname"];                  
    $b = $row["birthdate"];                  
    echo "<br /> $f " . $l
      .  "<br />Your date of birth is: " . $b;
  }
}  
//
mysql_close();     
?>
```

We use lastname LIKE '%$lname%' to select input user name.

And also, please not forget to add a space before onclick=:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="     Submit       "onclick = "check  ('lname');">
```

==>

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="     Submit       " onclick="check('lname');">
```

Answer (score 1):

First off don't use mysql_* functions like user4035 said. PDO allows you to design much more flexible scripts as they can be made to work with more databases than just MySQL.

If you really want to use a procedural coding style then this would be how you do it:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];  //you seem to not have a first name input as well in your form
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE firstname='$fname' AND lastname='$lname'");
```

you aren't querying with any search parameters just ordering after all results have been returned.
You could also add an "if" statement after you pull results.

```
...
$b=(mysql_result($s,$i,"birthdate"));
if($f==$fname&&$;==$lname){ //same result but don't do this.
...
```